# How to solve unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items' in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to do Schelling’s Segregation Model in Python which takes 6 parameters: the width and height of the city, the ratio of empty houses in the city, the similarity threshold, the number of iterations, and the number of races.
There are 4 methods within the Schelling class: populate, is_unsatisfied, update, move_to_empty, and plot.
This is the code:

```
class Schelling:
    def __init__(self, width, height, empty_ratio, similarity_threshold, n_iterations, races = 2):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.races = races
        self.empty_ratio = empty_ratio
        self.similarity_threshold = similarity_threshold
        self.n_iterations = n_iterations
        self.empty_houses = []
        self.agents = {}
 
    def populate(self):
        self.all_houses = list(itertools.product(range(self.width),range(self.height)))
        random.shuffle(self.all_houses)
 
        self.n_empty = int( self.empty_ratio * len(self.all_houses) )
        self.empty_houses = self.all_houses[:self.n_empty]
 
        self.remaining_houses = self.all_houses[self.n_empty:]
        houses_by_race = [self.remaining_houses[i::self.races] for i in range(self.races)]
        for i in range(self.races):
            #create agents for each race
            self.agents = dict(
                                self.agents.items() +
                                dict(zip(houses_by_race[i], [i+1]*len(houses_by_race[i]))).items()
                            )
 
    def is_unsatisfied(self, x, y):
 
        race = self.agents[(x,y)]
        count_similar = 0
        count_different = 0
 
        if x > 0 and y > 0 and (x-1, y-1) not in self.empty_houses:
            if self.agents[(x-1, y-1)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1
        if y > 0 and (x,y-1) not in self.empty_houses:
            if self.agents[(x,y-1)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1
        if x < (self.width-1) and y > 0 and (x+1,y-1) not in self.empty_houses:
            if self.agents[(x+1,y-1)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1
        if x > 0 and (x-1,y) not in self.empty_houses:
            if self.agents[(x-1,y)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1        
        if x < (self.width-1) and (x+1,y) not in self.empty_houses:
            if self.agents[(x+1,y)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1
        if x > 0 and y < (self.height-1) and (x-1,y+1) not in self.empty_houses:
            if self.agents[(x-1,y+1)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1        
        if x > 0 and y < (self.height-1) and (x,y+1) not in self.empty_houses:
            if self.agents[(x,y+1)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1        
        if x < (self.width-1) and y < (self.height-1) and (x+1,y+1) not in self.empty_houses:
            if self.agents[(x+1,y+1)] == race:
                count_similar += 1
            else:
                count_different += 1
 
        if (count_similar+count_different) == 0:
            return False
        else:
            return float(count_similar)/(count_similar+count_different) < self.happy_threshold
 
    def update(self):
        for i in range(self.n_iterations):
            self.old_agents = copy.deepcopy(self.agents)
            n_changes = 0
            for agent in self.old_agents:
                if self.is_unhappy(agent[0], agent[1]):
                    agent_race = self.agents[agent]
                    empty_house = random.choice(self.empty_houses)
                    self.agents[empty_house] = agent_race
                    del self.agents[agent]
                    self.empty_houses.remove(empty_house)
                    self.empty_houses.append(agent)
                    n_changes += 1
            print (n_changes)
            if n_changes == 0:
                break
 
    def move_to_empty(self, x, y):
        race = self.agents[(x,y)]
        empty_house = random.choice(self.empty_houses)
        self.updated_agents[empty_house] = race
        del self.updated_agents[(x, y)]
        self.empty_houses.remove(empty_house)
        self.empty_houses.append((x, y))
 
    def plot(self, title, file_name):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        #If you want to run the simulation with more than 7 colors, you should set agent_colors accordingly
        agent_colors = {1:'b', 2:'r', 3:'g', 4:'c', 5:'m', 6:'y', 7:'k'}
        for agent in self.agents:
            ax.scatter(agent[0]+0.5, agent[1]+0.5, color=agent_colors[self.agents[agent]])
 
        ax.set_title(title, fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
        ax.set_xlim([0, self.width])
        ax.set_ylim([0, self.height])
        ax.set_xticks([])
        ax.set_yticks([])
        plt.savefig(file_name)
```

Now that has an implementation of the Schelling class, can run different simulations and plot the results.
Build three simulations with the following characteristics:
width = 50, and height = 50 (2500 houses)
30% of empty houses
Similarity Threshold = 30% (for Simulation 1), Similarity Threshold = 50% (for Simulation 2), and Similarity Threshold = 80% (for Simulation 3)
Maximum number of iterations = 500
Number of races = 2
Start by creating and populating the cities.

```
schelling_1 = Schelling(50, 50, 0.3, 0.3, 500, 2)
schelling_1.populate()
 
schelling_2 = Schelling(50, 50, 0.3, 0.5, 500, 2)
schelling_2.populate()
 
schelling_3 = Schelling(50, 50, 0.3, 0.8, 500, 2)
schelling_3.populate()
```

After I run `schelling_1.populate()`, there is an error occurs.
The error is unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items' on

```
self.agents = dict(
                                self.agents.items() +
                                dict(zip(houses_by_race[i], [i+1]*len(houses_by_race[i]))).items()
                            )
```

How to make this error solve ?
Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in those lines?